# SQL - adding extra column makes the query sigificantly slower

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following (simplified) query.

When run without the specified column, Studio Manager executes the code instantaneously. When I add the 1 column, it takes 8 seconds to load.
When I add in the additional columns (Some calculated) that I have removed here for simplicity purposes, the difference goes up from instantaneous to 52 seconds.

I realize that without seeing the entire table structure its not easy to say what's going on, but can anyone come up with an idea of why this might be the case, or how to try solve the speed issue and make it process faster for this extra column?

Thanks

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 50 tblHoraotTashlum.*, 
Mossadname, mossadNumber, horaaStatusName, checkNumber
-- ADDING THIS FIELD  IS THE ISSUE:
--, tblEvents.eventType 

FROM [tblHoraotTashlum] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [tblEventCharges] ON tblHoraotTashlum.HoraaID  = [tblEventCharges].[horaaID] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblEvents ON tblEvents.eventID  = tblEventCharges.EventID  
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblMossadot ON tblHoraotTashlum.mossadID  = tblMossadot.mossadID  
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblHoraaStatus ON tblHoraotTashlum.StatusID  = tblHoraaStatus.horaaStatusID  
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblEventTypes ON tblEventTypes.typeID  = tblEvents.eventType  
WHERE ( tblMossadot.mossadID <> 114 ) 
ORDER BY tblHoraotTashlum.horaaid DESC
```

Comment: As you say, without delving in the table's DDL and query execution plan, it will be hard to troubleshoot. If you can test something, try creating this index `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCI_tblEvents ON tblEvents (eventID, eventType)` and executing the same query afterwards.

Comment: I assume when you same the columns are calculated, you mean that they are calculated columns, and not expressions in your `SELECT`. If so, are they `PERSISTED`? Like @EzLo said though, without the DDL any ideas are going to be purely guesswork.

Comment: Its all about which columns do you use. In your example you pull data from:
tblHoraaStatus  is lowest join operation that is needed for selected columns and WHERE. So tblHoraaStatus and tblEventTypes join is ignored by optimizer.

Please put all columns you need and provide query plan.

Comment: Check the execution plans. A possible reason is that the plan changed. Maybe a key lookup added because the previous index was covering or some other change in plan shape to retrieve the column value.

Comment: Were do these columns come from? `Mossadname, mossadNumber, horaaStatusName, checkNumber`

Comment: Likely the added column is not included in any index and require a table physical read, to verify this you can use the EXPLAIN command on Azure-MSSQL or the CTRL+M from SQL Server Management Studio connected to other ms-sql server versions

Comment: @EzLo - thanks. i tried this, but did not see any change.

Answer (score 0):

If `eventType` is the only column that actually relates to `tblEvents` in this query, adding it to the select clause will change the execution plan (without it, it might not even include any operations on tblEvents). Select speed issues are solved by correct indexing.

Here's a simple demonstration:

```
DECLARE @A AS TABLE
(
    AId int identity(1,1) primary key,
    Achar char(1)
)

INSERT INTO @A (Achar) VALUES ('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E');

DECLARE @B AS TABLE
(
    BId int identity(1,1) primary key,
    Bchar char(1)
)

INSERT INTO @B (Bchar) VALUES ('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E');



SELECT DISTINCT TOP 7 A.* 
FROM @A As A
LEFT OUTER JOIN @B As B 
    ON A.AId = B.BId
ORDER BY A.AId DESC

SELECT DISTINCT TOP 7 A.*, B.Bchar
FROM @A As A
LEFT OUTER JOIN @B As B 
    ON A.AId = B.BId
ORDER BY A.AId DESC
```

Note [the execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyeUmugEE) is very different for both queries:

[image]

In the first query, it only has a clustered index scan on the primary key of `@A`, while in the second query, it has clustered index scan on both tables primary keys and nested loops.

Seems like the query optimizer is smart enough to understand when a table in the from clause is not needed to get the results and simply ignores it completely.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation.- i think i get it. 
As to your question above `Mossadname` and `mossadNumber` are from from `tblMossadot`,  `horaaStatusName` is from `tblHoraaStatus` and checkNumber` is from `tblHoraotTashlum`

Here is my XML: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=By5pMebNE

Comment: You see the green `missing index` texts at the top of the execution plan? If you add these indexes it will improve the performance of the query.